# Return generic list

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I want to load a generic list. Therefore I want to use a function like :

```
public static <T> List<T> load()
{
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    List<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<T>();
    String fileExtension = toReturn.getClass().getComponentType().getSimpleName();
    ...
}
```

if you can see I want to get the Type ("T"), to search for files with these extensions. But if I call :

```
StorageUtil.<MyClass>load();
```

I get an Exception instead of getting "MyClass" as fileExtension. What's wrong on my code?

Comment: 'I get an Exception [...]' - please show the stacktrace!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that generics in Java don't work that way - you can't find the type of `T` at execution time due to *type erasure*. If you need the type at execution time, you can add a `Class<T>` parameter:

```
public static <T> List<T> load(Class<T> clazz) {
    ... use class.newInstance() to create a new instance, etc
}
```

See the [Java Generics FAQ entry for Type Erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html#Type%20Erasure) for more information.